# getting server name and port number in Ember Controller

Tags: ember.js

I need to make an AJAX call to my server from one of my controllers in Ember.  How do I get the server's name (or ip address) and port number?

Another words, if I access my application from http://192.168.33.10.com:8000/index.html, how do I get the 192.168.33.10:8000 part of the url.

Answer (score 1):

`document.location.host` will give you host:port, but you don't generally need that, just send requests to `'/path/something'` and the host:port is implied and the url is interpreted as `'http[s]://host:port//path/something'`